# How to achieve this on laravel 5 eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

How can i achieve something like this?

```
public function getInformation($model) {
  $result = $model::with(['province', 'city']);

  if($model == 'App\Models\Business') {
    $result->with(['businessProvince', 'businessCity']);
  }

  $result->get();
}

// call the function
$information->getInformation(\App\Models\Business::class);
```

i'm getting error

> Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be
>   converted to string

on the sample code above. Any suggestion is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem, thank you guys.

```
public function getInformation($model) {
  $result = $model::with(['province', 'city']);

  if($model == 'App\Models\Business') {
    // my mistake
    //$result->with(['businessProvince', 'businessCity']);

    $result = $result->with(['businessProvince', 'businessCity']);
  }

  $result->get();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After taking a fourth look `$model` should be a string, and `$result` is an Eloquent Builder instance and never an instance of the model class (since a query was started when `with` was called).

So the `$model == 'App\Models\Business'` I would change to `$model === \App\Models\Business::class` but that should not change the outcome.

Are you sure this error comes from this part of the application? Which line specifically?

---

Original **wrong** answer.

You are trying to compare the model instance with a string (since `$model::with()` created a instance of the model class you passed in the `$model` argument).

You can use the `instanceof` keyword for comparing an instance with a class name (http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php).

```
if($model instanceof \App\Models\Business) {
    $result->with(['businessProvince', 'businessCity']);
}
```

Comment: apart from the above suggestion put `$result = $model::with(['province', 'city']);` in else part of if condition.

Comment: Why would you do this? Than you have to put `$model::with(['province', 'city', 'businessProvince', 'businessCity']);` the this `if` part. Causing you to have to provide the province and city eager load twice in the same part of the code. IMHO this looks more readable.

Comment: its not working on my part. My goal is to reuse that method and only Business Model has the relationship of 'businessProvince' and 'businessCity'.

Comment: Even if i tried like this.
 $result = $model::with(['province', 'city']);
    $result->with(['businessProvince', 'businessCity']);
    $result->get();

Comment: You are correct, that is indeed not what is the problem, I modified the answer with hopefully a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: The error is not on the condition part, the error shows when you pass $model::with('relation') to $result variable. e.g $result = $model::with(['province', 'city']); then use the $result variable to chain another, like  $result->with(['businessProvince', 'businessCity']) or $result->get();

Comment: sorry for the confusing part of my question. :)

Comment: Hi @AlexBouma, i figure out my mistake. Thank for your response and time.